# »Naa, gieh mer fott mit dem Saupanz un seim Gekaschper!« What is that?

Tags: dialect

The sentence in quotation marks in the question line, apparently written in the dialect of Rhineland-Palatinate (Rheinland-Pfalz), appears in the article “[Aufwachen, Rheinland-Pfalz!](http://taz.de/Kolumne-Gehts-noch/!5404844/)” from *taz.de*. What does it mean? For context purposes, I'm forced to quote four paragraphs from the article (the sentence in question is in the last quoted paragraph and is highlighted in **bold**).

The introductory paragraph of the article reads:

> In Koblenz wollte sich ein Mann in „James Bond“ umbenennen. Das Verwaltungsgericht hat’s verboten. Ein großer Fehler.

The two paragraphs leading up to the paragraph where the sentence in question appears are:

> So ziemlich alles in dieser Resteverwertung aus Pfalz, Rheinprovinz und ein paar versprengten Exherzogtümern ist – na ja, so mittel: Mittelgebirge, Mittelrhein, mittelgut in Bildung, mittleres Bruttoinlandsprodukt. Rheinland-Pfalz ist kein Bad Boy, so wie Neonazi-Sachsen oder Ghetto-Bremen, aber eben auch kein Überflieger.
>
> Den Rheinland-PfälzerInnen mag das recht sein, die wollen ihre Ruhe.
>   Die strengen sich gerade genug an, um keine miesen Schlagzeilen zu
>   machen. Das muss aber auch reichen. Dann gibt’s wieder Weinchen. Und
>   in Tierorgane gestopfte Tierorgane (*the two latter sentence are, by the way, also abstruse*).

And, finally, the paragraph with the incomprehensible sentence:

> Aber einen großen Medienrummel um einen Mann, der jetzt James Bond heißt? Mit Kamerateams aus aller Welt und so? **Naa, gieh mer fott mit dem Saupanz un seim Gekaschper!**

From the ten words in the sentence, only *mit* and *dem* are in *dict.cc* (there's also a phrase, not very helpful though, with *mer*; and *Gekaschper* is possibly *Gekasper*, which is *clowning around*). So, what does the sentence in bold in the above paragraph mean? And, if you are not from Rhineland-Palatinate, do you understand what the sentence is saying?

Comment: There are no 'abstruse' sentences. This is just a sharply written polemic commentary, and for understanding all its allusions you need some background knowledge of the regional culture, cuisine, language, education policy in the various German provinces, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is clearly understandable for people who don't know *Pfälzisch*. Removing the dialect onomatopoeia, it reads:

> Nein, geh mir fort mit dem Saupanzen und seinem Gekasper.

*Geh mir fort!* is a fixed phrase meaning *I don't need this stuff*. More literally it means *F#CK OFF (I don't need your stuff)* but today it's more used in a heated dispute than for the purpose shooing some hawker.

Literally *Panz* or *Pänz* just means kid, but it's often used for kids who are little menaces. *Sau* is *sow* so *Saupanz* is a stinking brat.

*Gekasper* is the act of clowning around as you found out yourself.

---

> Dann gibt’s wieder Weinchen.

*Than they have a small wine.*

> Und in Tierorgane gestopfte Tierorgane

*And intestines put into intestines.* (It's sausage made from intestines.)

Comment: Good answer, but I don't see why we should follow the US American bigotry of hiding curse words behind a beep in TV or placeholder spelling in writing. If you want to say "fuck" in Europe you are allowed to say "fuck" and write "fuck". Z#m K#ck#ck!

Comment: Because this is an U.S. site and some wacky U.S. guy or gal may come and reprimand me for doing so. Been there, seen that.